# Directly convert .aspx to .pdf

Tags: asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation

A project I am working on requires me to build a report that is output in both HTML (.aspx) and as a PDF. Is there a solution available that allows me to feed the output of an .aspx page to a PDF generation utility? Full support of HTML and CSS would be ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far! One thing I should probably clarify... the web application is secured with web forms and an SSL cert. Hopefully this won't be a problem. From what I'm reading ABCpdf and wkhtmltopdf seem to be the best options. ABCpdf seems to be better integrated with .NET, wkhtmltopdf probably does a much better job of rendering complex CSS though since it uses the WebKit rendering engine. The CSS will probably be semi-complex and there may be images (charts, etc) added in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) will do it.... USAGE:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf
```

That is it.  You can go to any web page... even aspx.  css is supported better than any other utility as it uses the webkit html rendering engine (Safari, Chrome).  Enjoy

There is a single .exe (7 mb) that can be used from .Net simply by using Process.Start
Make sure that you copy the exe into your project directory or you have to specify the full path.
ex:

```
static void HtmlToPdf(string website,string destinationFile)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "wkhtmltopdf.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = website+" "+destinationFile;
        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
```

I think SSL is supported but I do not think that 2-way SSL would work at the moment.  It is hands down the best single stop HTML -> PDF tool I have seen.

Comment: Works very nice, even with my web hosting (web-app generates pdf invoices)

Comment: I found it to break some pages - check this one for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BgNPC/8/

Answer (score 3):

[iTextSharp](https://itextpdf.com/) can do HTML to PDF, but only basic HTML and CSS not full support.

Some articles on sending HTML to iTextSharp:

http://somewebguy.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/itextsharp-simplify-your-html-to-pdf-creation/

http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-export-content-of-gridview-to.html

[http://geekswithblogs.net:80/casualjim/archive/2005/11/13/59943.aspx#393262](https://web.archive.org/web/20200111042752/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/casualjim/archive/2005/11/13/59943.aspx#393262)

Answer (score 3):

I used [HTMLDoc](http://www.hotels-of-london.com/easyswcom/) in the past it did a good job of turning HTML tables, images etc with some basic formatting into a decent PDF report. There also seems to be an [open source version](https://web.archive.org/web/20170116153628/https://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1) as well.

[iTextSharp](https://itextpdf.com/) renders html at a basic level.

I found that hacking in a simple HTML renderer allowed me to offer PDF functionality immediately and then i had to backfit a PDF report renderer later. This should be pretty simple if you keep your presentation layer separate from your data and business logic.

I used [PDFlib](https://www.pdflib.com/) then but both [iTextSharp](https://itextpdf.com/) and [PDFlib](https://www.pdflib.com/) are awesome libraries for programatically creating PDF from your data sources.

I haven't seen a perfect HTML 2 PDF renderer yet, so i would plan for a two stage approach. You may also want to look at [this question](https://web.archive.org/web/20130302101728/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/177/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-pdf-in-my-net-application) for other options.

Comment: @Jle's suggestion of wkhtmltopdf sounds like a better replacement to htmldoc.

Answer (score 0):

> AspPDF is an ActiveX server component for dynamically creating, reading and modifying Portable Document Format (PDF) files.

http://www.asppdf.com

Answer (score 0):

[ActivePDF WebGrabber](http://www.activepdf.com/products/serverproducts/webgrabber2009/) is a great product once you have everything configured correctly.  It's costly, but it has awesome support of HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

We've used the [Alt-Soft XML2PDF](https://alt-soft.com/) product for this purpose. It can convert any XML file to PDF using the [XSL-FO markup language](https://web.archive.org/web/20150131091855/http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/default.asp).

So if your ASPX pages are XHTML compatible, Xml2PDF will convert those into PDF quite happily and easily. Here's a sample page - complete with a downloadable ASP.NET sample - that show how that works: http://www.alt-soft.com/products_HTML2PDF.aspx

It's not free, but well worth its license price!

Marc

Answer (score 0):

http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-convert-web-page-to-pdf.html
Shows you how to override Render and change the content to PDF using iTextSharp

Answer (score 0):

This is the best control to convert ASPX page to PDF:

http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/EOPdf/ASPXToPDF.aspx

It's an ASP.NET server control that you can just drop into your page. It automatically handles ASP.NET authentication and sessions. So you can convert your current page even if the page request login and uses session data.

Comment: i am unable to download it from either server

Comment: How can i download it ?