# how to convert aspx page in to PDF

Tags: asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Directly convert .aspx to .pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220423/directly-convert-aspx-to-pdf)
>   [Generating PDF documents in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355837/generating-pdf-documents-in-asp-net)

I have aspx page , and I want to save as pdf format on button click event. Please help

Comment: you want to convert your Gridview data to PDF or your whole page ?

Comment: there are plenty of applications and libraries that can convert html to PDF - you may use any for your problem.