# How to convert aspx page to pdf file?

Tags: asp.net, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Directly convert .aspx to .pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220423/directly-convert-aspx-to-pdf)

I have made one aspx page and generated chart on it through chart control of asp.net.
But i am not able to generate this generated chart to pdf document. i want to make my aspx page as pdf document. Thank you in advance for support.

Comment: does your page includes flash(for charting) ?

Comment: Try searching for 'aspx pdf' on stackoverflow, this question is asked at least once a week.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this for yourself, or do you want your visitors to be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to convert the aspx page to pdf that means inturn you are going to convert the rendered html to pdf so here is a good link that may help you though i did not tried it but looks promising

[It's Here](http://hamang.net/2008/08/14/html-to-pdf-in-net/)

NB:I am assuming that your page does not include any flash charting.

Answer (score -1):

use itextsharp.dll I m sure you can get ur page in pdf using this dll
very easy to implement.

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
```

// This will be on button's click

```
  string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + filename+ ".pdf";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
    htextw.AddStyleAttribute("font-size", "7pt");
    htextw.AddStyleAttribute("color", "Black");

    Panel_Name.RenderControl(htextw);//Name of the Panel
    Document document = new Document();
    document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5, 5, 15, 5);
    FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 50, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLUE);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
    document.Open();

    StringReader str = new StringReader(stw.ToString());
    HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(document);
    htmlworker.Parse(str);

    document.Close();
    Response.Write(document);
```

Paste this some where on page

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{


}
```

Comment: i have tried to use itextshart.dll but it gives me error of illegal character used on line - obj.Parse(se);

Comment: paste some code so that I can check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742560/how-to-generate-pdf-file-dynamically-on-click-of-a-link-button-without-loading-th/6924598#6924598 check out if this can help u