# Converting aspx to pdf

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have use ItextSharp to generate pdf file from an aspx page.

But it gives me an error in an obj.Parse(se), where se is the string reader and it takes the path of:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I am stuck with this problem.

Please help and give suggesstion.

Thank You

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
using iTextSharp.text.xml;
using System.Xml;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
public partial class Pdf : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter twr = new StreamWriter(mem);
    HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(twr);
    base.Render(myWriter);
    myWriter.Flush();
    myWriter.Dispose();
    StreamReader strmRdr = new StreamReader(mem);
    strmRdr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
    string pageContent = strmRdr.ReadToEnd();
    strmRdr.Dispose();
    mem.Dispose();
    writer.Write(pageContent);
    CreatePDFDocument(pageContent);


 }
 public  void CreatePDFDocument(string strHtml)
 {

    string strFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("test.pdf");
    // step 1: creation of a document-object
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2:
    // we create a writer that listens to the document
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create));
    StringReader se = new StringReader(strHtml);
    HTMLWorker obj = new HTMLWorker(document);
    document.Open();
    obj.Parse(se);
    document.Close();
    ShowPdf(strFileName);



 }
 public void ShowPdf(string strFileName)
 {
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + strFileName);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.WriteFile(strFileName);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Clear();
}
}
```

Comment: Care to share the error message with us?

Comment: check out this link if it can help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702884/how-to-convert-aspx-page-to-pdf-file/6703583#6703583

Comment: A better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1220423/2291

Comment: I'd also warn you against using HtmlWorker for any complex layout. It has a VERY limited parsing capability and unless you are pushing very simple XHTML in you should think about building the PDF in code

Comment: Can you post the error? You might want to consider purchasing a component to do this for you. Its well worth the money and the time it will save you easily pays itself back. While the free components tend to work ok, I've hit alot of edge cases with them. I've use ABCPDF.Net [http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm] and it worked really well for everything I threw at it. You can download a free trial to test it out.

Comment: **answer your own question** after you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that worked for me.  There is a bit of code but it shows ways you can take advantage of things like css.  Hope it helps.

```
private void ExportToPDF()
{
    string s = "<table><td><tr>First<b>row</b></tr></td></table>";
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 30, 30, 60, 35);
    MemoryStream msReport = new MemoryStream();
    string strHTMLpath = Server.MapPath("../myHTML.html");
    string strPDFpath = Server.MapPath("../myPDF.pdf");
    try
    {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        StreamWriter strWriter = new StreamWriter(strHTMLpath, false, Encoding.UTF8);
        strWriter.Write(s.ToString());
        strWriter.Close();
        strWriter.Dispose();
        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
        styles.LoadTagStyle("ol", "leading", "16,0");
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(strPDFpath, FileMode.Create));
        document.Add(new Header(iTextSharp.text.html.Markup.HTML_ATTR_STYLESHEET, "Style.css"));
        document.Open();
        ArrayList objects;
        styles.LoadTagStyle("li", "face", "garamond");
        styles.LoadTagStyle("span", "size", "8px");
        styles.LoadTagStyle("body", "font-family", "times new roman");
        styles.LoadTagStyle("body", "font-size", "10px");
        document.NewPage();
        objects = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.
        HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StreamReader(strHTMLpath, Encoding.Default), styles);
        for (int k = 0; k < objects.Count; k++)
        {
            document.Add((IElement)objects[k]);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        document.Close();
        Response.Write(strPDFpath);
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myFileName.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.WriteFile(strPDFpath);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        File.Delete(strPDFpath);
    }
}
```