# how to generate pdf file dynamically on click of a link button without loading the page

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a user control which has a panel used to display the information which I print when needed.
I have a grid view in which I get search result It has a link button clicking on which I want to open a pdf of that panel in the above one.

Comment: Showing the relevant code would help. Did you miss that last statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented this, and I hope someone else can do it as well. I have listed my code below.

```
    using iTextSharp.text;
    using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
    using iTextSharp.text.html;
    using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
```

Import the above DLL

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + "File Name" + ".pdf";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
    htextw.AddStyleAttribute("font-size", "7pt");
    htextw.AddStyleAttribute("color", "Black");
    Page pg = new Page();
    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
    pg.EnableEventValidation = false;

    pg.RenderControl(htextw);
    Document document = new Document();
    document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5, 5, 15, 5);
    FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 50, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLUE);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
    document.Open();
    //This is how you can add text in div in a pdf
    Chunk c = new Chunk(TextHere + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 15));
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    p.Add(c); p.Add(c1);
    // This is how you can generate table and can set proprties
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.WidthPercentage = 100;
    //Bill No and Bill Date
    PdfPCell pdfcell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Text in TAble" + "TExt From Database"));
    pdfcell1.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER | iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.TOP_BORDER;
    table.AddCell(pdfcell1);
    PdfPCell pdfcell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Text in TAble" + "TExt From Database"));
    pdfcell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER | iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.TOP_BORDER;
    pdfcell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
    table.AddCell(pdfcell);

    document.Add(p);
    document.Add(table);
    document.Add(tablegrid);
    StringReader str = new StringReader(stw.ToString());
    HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(document);
    htmlworker.Parse(str);

    document.Close();
    Response.Write(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might run into some trouble on this one. You can't do this all client-side, since JavaScript can not manipulate files (by design).
So your options are:

1. Full postback
2. Ajax call

You could try an Ajax call to a custom handler (`.ashx`) file whick returns a response with the PDF file. I havn't tried this before, but it might work. How about opening another page with `target="_blank"` and it will run the server-side code and generate the PDF, while the original page remains where it was?

Comment: I can do this using server side code as well, can you help me with that

Comment: I think your best bet is to use one of the many compenents that do this already. Some are better than others and some are even free. Just have a quick search on Google and you'll find a handfull.

Comment: U didnt get my question my friend please read the question and then provide solution not just writting anything do this do that

Comment: I think you my friend don't understand the point of this Q&A site. No one here is going to write your code for you! I am pointing you in the right direction. If you have a specific problem, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: did u really get my problem, I want to show a user control in pdf dynamically. that control is not visible yet

Comment: ok let me tell you what I m doing hope we can solve this problem 
I m generating panel dynamically I m passing values to the control inside the panel then I m trying to render it. so tell me now M i moving in the right direction

Comment: I took me a long time to find how can I add text to pdf dynamically on the page I have mention that in my above edited code