# Is it possible to convert an html page to a pdf with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to generate pdf of my webpage. Is it possible? if not then what can be done to get a pdf form which has the data from the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Directly convert .aspx to .pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220423/directly-convert-aspx-to-pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you need this for, you can create a PDF via the Print menu in Chrome (Save to PDF is a "printer").

Comment: All browsers on the Windows platform have the print to PDF driver.  It's part of Windows 7-10.  Not sure about XP.